# Automate the process of uploading and starting the template to Nifi in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, apache-nifi

A Nifi template with specific logic is available. After deploying **Nifi** on **Kubernetes**, the template includes processors containing sensitive fields such as passwords. The current process involves manually opening the UI post-deployment, uploading the template, entering sensitive data, and starting the Nifi flow. Is there a way to automate these steps when deploying Nifi on Kubernetes?

I wanted the automated process of nifi without manually executing the steps.